# wrap image and force same size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a image and a div which wraps the image. On load the div has the exact same size as the image but when I resize the image, the div doesn't adapt the width of the image.

See the problem in this fiddle I tested with Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/8pLed/

Seems like

```
display: inline;
```

is not the solution

**Edit:**

This is how it looks after I changed the size of the window:

[image]

Comment: It works as expected resizing the height  at max of 100% of the browsers size ...

Comment: don't understand problem...when I resize window image does too. If you have code that does image resize....need to show that

Comment: Have you tested it with Chrome 31.0? In the Firefox or Safari I don't have this problem

Answer (score 0):

`style="width: 100%;"` is needed to re-size image according to the browser's width.

Also you can use

```
style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;"
```

but the img element won't be static.

You are using `width: auto` which sets width of image in contrast of aspect ratio from height.